# Media Queries don't work on desktop

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have the following media queries which work on a mobile, but the default does not work on a desktop:

```
@media (min-width:481px) {
.header-section { width: auto; }
.search-block { display:none; }
}
@media (min-width:320px) {
.header-section { width: auto; }
.search-block { display:none; }
}
```

These work on mobiles, but when I view on desktop, the default CSS which is displayed below and not under any media query does not kick in. In my google inspector, I can see media="all" for these rules but it still doesn't work and applies the media queries meant for the mobile. Any ideas?

```
.search-block {
width: 500px;
float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: The important distinctions to make here are: what browser you're using and what resolution you are viewing the page at. Mobile browsers will not be the same as desktop ones, even if they are both "Chrome" (for example). To determine the browser compatibility for a feature, I suggest using: http://caniuse.com/. Also, you may mean to use `max-width` instead of `min-width`. Using `min-width` means that anything greater than the supplied value will use that media query (unless another one overwrites it).

Comment: You do realize that your desktop browser is almost certainly at least 320px wide, right?

Answer (score 1):

In specifying *only* `(min-width:320px)` as a media feature you're targetting **all** media types whose width is **greater than** 320px. This means that unless your desktop browser's width is less than 320px, this styling will be applied.

To demonstrate what 320px looks like, here's a 320x320 placeholder image. If your browser is unable to fully display this image your media query will always take effect:

[image: 320px example]

If you want to only target smartphones (with width greater than 320px), you'll want to add a `max-width` media feature to your current query to prevent the styling being applied on media types which are wider than 480px:

```css
@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width:480px) {
    .header-section { width: auto; }
    .search-block { display:none; }
}
```

*Note that 480px is just a general smartphone maximum width and not a guideline for all smartphones.*

---

To show this in action I've created [**this JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zBBxG/).

In this demo I've added two dividers, `example1` and `example2`. `example1` is only contained within a `min-width` media query and `example2` is contained in a `max-width` query. As long as JSFiddle's result frame's width isn't between 100px and 200px, `example2` will always be green. `example1` on the other hand will always be red unless the frame is less than 100px wide.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the @media query has an importance in your CSS

it helped for me to
make the role for the smallest display
followed by the next biggest display
and so on till you last query for the biggest screen

example:

```
.your-class{
  width: 50%
}
@media (min-width: 480px){
  .your-class{
    width: 33%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .your-class{
    width: 25%
  }
}
```

if you prefer to take the `max-width` then invert the order from biggest screen to smallest